# Exception declaration on RxJava or Reactor

Tags: rx-java, project-reactor

Supposed that I have some API which returns Observable. How to tell the API clients/users that the API may throw certain exception?

In plain Java, it's very simple:

```
List<Student> findStudentsByGrade(int grade) 
  throws NegativeGradeException, DataRetrievalFailureException {
}
```

If we change it into Observable, it'd be not clear.

```
Observable<Student> findStudentsByGrade(int grade) {

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using checked exceptions might allow you to convey the message that "a method has this identified type of error condition", but it is really tied to imperative synchronous programming.

In reactive programming the errors are propagated down your asynchronous stream of data through the `onError` signal, because said errors could have happened anywhere up the stream (including on other threads and other parts of your program).

In such a reactive stream, everything happens asynchronously (as data becomes available and traverses the `Flux`) and **nothing happen until there is a `subscribe(...)`** (which can be done much later in the execution). So conceptually everything becomes more or less a runtime exception.

Even if your method works on a `Flux`/`Observable` and returns a `Flux`/`Observable`, it probably only describes the expected output behavior by adding more operators to it, but doesn't actually process any data and isn't really the site from where the errors will happen.

You can still of course let such a method throw something like a `NullPointerException` (or a relevant checked exception) if you want to validate parameters or signal issues that completely prevent the `Flux`/`Observable` to be created, but not data-related errors (as execution will happen at a later time).

That sort of information will need to go into the documentation/javadoc of your reactive API (and we recommend using subclasses of `RuntimeException` instead of any checked `Exception` you'd like to propagate to your users).

Comment: That means, no Javadoc annotation for that for sure. Users must read carefully what the stream may throw. Am I right?

Comment: you could use the `@throws` javadoc tag, even though the exception isn't checked-and-part-of-the-throws-clause. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javadoc.html#CHDCHAHD

Answer (score 0):

If an exception inside your pipeline happens,then your subscriber will receive the throwable in the onError callback

```
@Test
public void observableOnErrorResumeException() {
    Integer[] numbers = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5};

    Observable.from(numbers)
            .doOnNext(number -> {
                if (number > 3) {
                    try {
                        throw new IllegalArgumentException();
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        throw new RuntimeException(e);
                    }
                }

            })
            .doOnError(t-> System.out.println("Exception happens "+t.getMessage()))
            .subscribe(n -> System.out.println("onNext:"+n),e -> System.out.println("onRrror:"+e.getMessage()),System.out::println);


}
```

This test will print

```
onNext:0
onNext:1
onNext:2
onNext:3
onRrror:java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
```

If you want to see more examples take a look here https://github.com/politrons/reactive

Comment: Hi Paul. I'm looking how to make it clear to other fellow developers that a stream might throw certain exceptions. I guess, no other way except to read the documentation properly, because the method signature won't help.

Comment: You can set in your pipeline onError operator then it's clear that you want to control a possible throwable

Comment: Sorry. I still don't get you, could you please give me an example?